# (How) Can I rotate the camera in the Open3D visualization window?

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

I want to use python code to make the camera follow a preprogrammed trajectory of a point cloud visualization in Open3D, both including rotations and translations. How can I do so? And if this is not possible, are there any other solutions that I might be able to use?

I have looked at the Open3D documentation but could not find any solution there.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://github.com/dfki-ric/pytransform3d/discussions/148) :

```
import sys
import json
import numpy as np
import pytransform3d.transformations as pt
import pytransform3d.camera as pc
import pytransform3d.visualizer as pv


mesh_filename = sys.argv[-2]
camera_filename = sys.argv[-1]

with open(camera_filename, "r") as f:
    cameras = json.load(f)

camera_poses = cameras["poses"]
camera_intrinsics = cameras["intrinsics"][0]

px_focal_length = float(camera_intrinsics["pxFocalLength"])
px_principal_point_x = float(camera_intrinsics["principalPoint"][0])
px_principal_point_y = float(camera_intrinsics["principalPoint"][1])
M = np.array([
    [px_focal_length, 0, px_principal_point_x],
    [0, px_focal_length, px_principal_point_y],
    [0, 0, 1]
])
sensor_size = (float(camera_intrinsics["width"]), float(camera_intrinsics["height"]))

transformation_matrices = np.empty((len(camera_poses), 4, 4))
for i, camera_pose in enumerate(camera_poses):
    R = np.array(list(map(float, camera_pose["pose"]["transform"]["rotation"]))).reshape(3, 3)
    p = np.array(list(map(float, camera_pose["pose"]["transform"]["center"])))
    transformation_matrices[i] = pt.transform_from(R=R, p=p)


fig = pv.figure()
fig.plot_mesh(mesh_filename)
for pose in transformation_matrices:
    fig.plot_transform(A2B=pose, s=0.1)
    fig.plot_camera(M=M, cam2world=pose, virtual_image_distance=0.1, sensor_size=sensor_size)
fig.show()
```